# Newton Integral Convergence

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

please, I have a problem. I suppose it´s quite easy, however, I really don´t see what should I do with it.

I should decide on convergence or divergence of this integral:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}\:dx$$

I don´t want to find primitive function of indefinite integral, because I guess it should be possible to solve it with using some convergence test.

There is obviously problem with $x=0$, where to integrated function $f(x)$ isn´t continuous. It is continuous on the rest of interval and it is also positive, so I could compare it with some $g(x)$ which is more or equal to $f(x)$, but I think that it isn´t a good idea in this case when $\lim_{x \to 0} = \infty$.

I also don´t see how should I use Limit test, just don´t see what to compare with.

But as I've said, I suppose it will be very easy, but I don´t see it.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** The integrand is a continuous function on $(0,\infty)$, thus the potential problems are near $0$ and near $\infty$.

As $x \to 0^+$, you have, for $b$ sufficiently near $0^+$:
$$
\int_0^b \frac{1}{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}dx \sim \int_0^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx 
$$ and the last integral is convergent.

As $x \to +\infty$, you have, for $b$ sufficiently great:
$$
\int_b^\infty \frac{1}{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}dx  =2\int_\sqrt{b}^\infty \frac{u}{e^u-1}du <2\int_\sqrt{b}^\infty \frac{1}{u^2}du<+\infty \quad (e^u>u^3+1)
$$ and the last integral is convergent.

Then your initial integral is **convergent**.

Comment: Oh, tahnk you very much. I understand the problem theoretically, but I just  didn't find the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, although it's so clear! Thank you very much, it really helped me!

Comment: @David You are very welcome!